# Make Caption of "lstinputlisting" in Minipage Centred with Respect to *Both* Minipages

Tags: listings, captions, minipage

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\newlisting}[4]{
\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[language=Java, showstringspaces=\false, tabsize=4, basicstyle=\tiny, keywordstyle=\bfseries, breaklines=true, caption=THIS IS THE CAPTION I WOULD LIKE TO CENTRE, captionpos=mb]{#2}
\end{minipage}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
\begin{minipage}{#3\linewidth}
\resizebox{8.0em}{8.0em}{#4}
}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Where I have "THIS IS THE CAPTION I WOULD LIKE TO CENTRE" I would like to have it such that the caption that appears there, currently underneath its own minipage, actually appears centred with respect to BOTH minipages.

I'm not sure if I can do some sort of jiggery pokery with definitions, but if I enclose all of the above in a Figure environment then that seems to discombobulate the numbering of other Listings.

Many thanks

Comment: Please make your code compilable (MWE).

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise it wasn't. I've found the problem now but can only select my own answer as the "right" one in two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised `captionof` would probably be the answer but couldn't get it working as I wanted UNLESS it was before both minipages. My mistake ...

```
\newcommand{\newlisting}[4]{
\captionof{lstlisting}[CAPTION]{CITE}
\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[language=Java, showstringspaces=\false, tabsize=4, basicstyle=\tiny, keywordstyle=\bfseries, breaklines=true]{#2}
\end{minipage}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
\begin{minipage}{#3\linewidth}
\resizebox{8.0em}{8.0em}{#4}
}
\end{minipage}
}
```